# Trying to use MATCH vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, match

I'm trying to get a value on a colum and a value on a row.

I did this and it works:

```
linha = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(nome, Sheets(2).Range("a:a"), 0)
```

But if i do this, it don't work. Supose to be the same code (error 1004)

```
x = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
linha2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(nome, Sheets(2).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, 1)), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work because if you qualify the Range object with Sheet reference, you also need to qualify the Cells with the Sheet reference.

Try it like this...

```
linha2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(nome, Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)), 0)
```

Comment: thank you ".Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)" worked

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

If `nome` is not found in the range it will error, so we need some error handling.

You need to add the parentage to the Cells() inside the Range():

```
Dim linha2 As Long
Dim x As Long
linha2 = 0
x = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
    linha2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(nome, Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If linha2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox nome & " not found in range"
Else
    'do what you want with linha2
End If
```

Comment: thank you ".Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)" worked